# Alternative for 4 nested for loops when working with dictionaries with different lengths

Tags: python, dictionary, time, response

For a python project I'm a bit stuck at the following.

There is a list `dictlist` with n dictionaries of different lengths stored in it. Now I would like to compare each key of one dict to all other keys of all other dictionaries, such that when the similarity measure of a key passes a certain threshold, the values should also be compared to each other. Then the average similarity of the 'chosen' values should be saved in a similarity matrix. Because n is quite big (1780), the 4 for loops are taking a huge amount of time. Please see the code below that does what I would like to achieve. But as mentioned, this is taking way too long.

```
    n = len(dictlist)
    avg_simij = np.empty((n, n), float)
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(0,n):
            ij_vsimilarity = []
                for x in range(0,len(dictlist[i].keys())):
                    for y in range(0,len(dictlist[j].keys())):
                            onekey_oneproduct = list(dictlist[i].keys())[x]
                            otherkey_otherproduct = list(dictlist[j].keys())[y]
                            similarity = function(onekey_oneproduct,otherkey_otherproduct, n=1)
                            if similarity > 0.4:
                                if (len(list(dictlist[i].values())[x]) != 0 & len(list(dictlist[j].values())[y]) != 0):
                                    onevalue_oneproduct = list(dictlist[i].values())[x]
                                    othervalue_otherproduct = list(dictlist[j].values())[y]
                                    vsimilarity = function(onevalue_oneproduct,othervalue_otherproduct, n=1)
                                    ij_vsimilarity.append(vsimilarity)
                if len(ij_vsimilarity) != 0:
                  avg_simij[i][j] = sum(ij_vsimilarity) / len(ij_vsimilarity)
                else:
                  avg_simij[i][j] = 0
```

Someone already recommended me to do these comparisons in numpy arrays. However, when trying this, I can't think of a way to compare arrays of different lengths

```
keys1 = np.array(list(dictlist[0].keys()))
keys2 = np.array(list(dictlist[1].keys()))
keys1 == keys1 # Comparison works and returns a list with True values
keys1 == keys2 # Comparison doesn't work because of dictionaries having different lengths
```

Could someone help me a bit further with a faster algorithm?

EDIT:
Good idea from the comments to include an example input

```
#Input:
  dictlist = [{'Animal': 'Lion',
  'Country': 'SA',
  'type': 'CARN'},
 {'Animal-type': 'Lions',
  'State': '0.2',
  'Food': 'Meat',
'Country': 'South-Africa'}] # when n = 2


#Output:
avg_simij = array([[1, 0.5],[0.1, 1]]) 
# This would be the output for n = 2, with avg_simij[0][1] = 0.5 
# denoting that the item 0 and 1 are quite similar. 
# The diagonal of this array should consist out of ones 
# because an item is 100% similar with itself.
```

Comment: would be great to provide a minimal example of input/output

Comment: If you're concerned about speed, then as first thing, you should avoid repeatedly performing relatively expensive operations only to throw the result away and do the same thing again and again. Just as an example, you have `list(dictlist[i].values())` twice in the inner-most loop, meaning you construct the exact same list of values `j * x * y * 2` times (only to extract a single element out of it, get its length, throw it away, create the same list again, and get the same element of it once more).

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks, your suggestion already reduced the running time significantly